# Splitting and grouping strings by size of group

Tags: ruby

Given a string of various length, that will either contain all the same letter

```
str0 = 'AAAAAAA'
```

or at most two different letters at various frequencies

```
str1 = 'AABBBBAAABBB'
```

how can we split and group this string into an array where the first element will be the count of the letter with the greater frequency and the second element the count of the smaller frequecy i.e. for `str1`

```
arr = [7, 5]
```

as `B` appears 7 times and `A` appears 5 times.  In the case of strings of even length and equal frequecny, order in the array is irrelevant.

So far, I have

```
str = 'AABBBBAAABBB'
arr = str.split("").group_by {|x| x}.values
arr.each_with_object([]){|x, tmp_arr| tmp_arr << x.size}.sort.reverse 
[7, 5]
```

It seems like there must be a better and cleaner way to do this, especially without needlessly creating a hash, as `group_by` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. `each_with_object` can be replaced with `map` in this case, since this is exactly what `map` is for, and `split("")` can be replaced with `chars`:

```
str = 'AABBBBAAABBB'
arr = str.chars.group_by {|x| x}.values.map(&:length).sort.reverse
```

---

> especially without needlessly creating a hash, as group_by does

I wouldn't really call that "needless". In fact, I suspect the use of a hash here is a much more efficient implementation than most alternatives.

If efficiency is a big concern, there are lots of things you could do to optimize the code in question. I doubt any such "optimized" solution would be as readable as the one above though.

Comment: That's a very nice bit of Ruby there.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.uniq.map{|l| arr.count(l)}.sort.reverse
```

use `str.chars` to get the array

enjoy :)